# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir using pnpm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pnpm

I tried everything, deleted cache, node_modules, changed permission of all my folders to Full Control and nothing worked, please help me guys

````
builder:build: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir 'C:\Users\User\Work\MyTalk\typebot.io\apps\builder\.next\standalone\node_modules\@prisma\client'] {
builder:build:   errno: -4048,
builder:build:   code: 'EPERM',
builder:build:   syscall: 'scandir',
builder:build:   path: 'C:\\Users\\User\\Work\\MyTalk\\typebot.io\\apps\\builder\\.next\\standalone\\node_modules\\@prisma\\client'```
````

Comment: try deleting the .next folder and run your command again.